# Command wc-1 returns illegal option

Tags: unix

I'm working my way through a unix tutorial. Contrary to the expectations bestowed upon me by the tutorial when I enter the command

```
wc -1
```

I get the following

```
wc: illegal option -- 1
usage: wc [-clmw] [file ...]
```

Can anyone explain this and how i can use wc -1 to determine how many users are logged in

Comment: `-1` is not a valid option to `wc`. `-l` is, which the message is telling you when it says `[-clmw]`; `-c`, `-l`, `-m`, and `-w` are the as valid flags for your version of `wc`. `-1` is not in that list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe it was

```
wc -l
```

l for larry not number 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misreaded `wc -l` (lowcase L, not number one), which counts the number of lines of standard input.

To count the number of users logged in, use this:

```
users | wc -l
```

`|` is a special symbol of the shell, that redirects the standard output of the first command to the standard input of the second, by using Unix pipes.

(`users` prints the list of logged in users to standard output.)